# How to beat my CodeIgniter bad practices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Accessing functions from the view?
I know the correct way should be that the controllers handles all the function calls, but 
If I need to call another function and pass a variable that comes from a db data in a loop in view  eg.

view:

```
if($persons != ""){

   foreach($persons as $p){
       echo $p->name;
       echo $p->lastname;
       // Now I need to call a function and pass parameters from loop
       $is_banned = $this->model_users->checkIfBanned($p->name);
       echo $is_banned;

   }
}
```

How should I do this the right way in the controller?

Other thing is the javascript ajax calls. I have been putting lots of javascript in the controllers when I need to receive more than one response. For instance, if i need to get all the posts from a user via ajax and get the response to update the posts div, plus get the number of posts and update the post count div.

The wrong way I've been doing:
eg. js:

```
function insertNewPost(){
var the_text = $('#post_text_input').val();
if(the_text != ""){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:base_url+"controller/insertNewPost",
    data: {post_text: the_text},
    cache:false,
    success:function(response){
              $('#post_output').prepend(response);
              $('#post_text_input').val('');

    }
});


}
```

Controller:

```
function insertNewPost(){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $this->load->model('model_posts');
            $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
            $myid = $this->model_users->getUserId($email);
            $post_text= $this->FilterData($this->input->post('post_text'));


            if($this->model_posts->insertNewPost($myid,$post_text)){
                $count = $this->model_posts->countPosts($myid);
                echo  'More recent: '.$post_text;?>

                <script>
                    var count = "<?php echo $count;?>";
                    $('#posts_count').html(count);     

                </script>

                <?php


            } 
       }else{
               redirect("inicio");
            }

}
```

Is it possible to get 2 responses at the same time and update content from 2 divs at the same time? How would I get hold of the `$count`  variable and pass it on the same ajax response?

Any light shed would be very greatful.
Thanks in advance

As suggested by @charlietfl:

Changed the Controller:

```
function insertNewPost(){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $this->load->model('model_posts');
            $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
            $myid = $this->model_users->getUserId($email);
            $post_text= $this->FilterData($this->input->post('post_text'));


            if($this->model_posts->insertNewPost($myid,$post_text)){

                $content = 'More recent: '.$post_text;
                $count = $this->model_posts->countPosts($myid);
                $items = array($content,$count);
                echo json_encode($items);


            } 
       }else{
               redirect("inicio");
            }

}
```

And changed the js function:

```
function insertNewPost(){
var the_text = $('#post_text_input').val();
var post_count = '#posts_count';
if(the_text != ""){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:base_url+"controller/insertNewPost",
    data: {post_text: the_text},
    cache:false,
    success:function(response){
                var content = json_encode(response);   
                 $('#post_output').prepend(content[0]);
                $(post_count).html(content[1]);
                $('#post_text_input').val('');




    }
});


}
```

it's not happening, i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: can create associative array in php and output as json then ajax success can parse the returned object properties to do whatever is needed

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. That sounds good, will try it out and post results.Any idea for the first problem?

Comment: not really sure what your first problem is. Passing data from controller to view is well documented in CI docs

Comment: you need to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) instead of json_encode on the js function

Comment: @AbrahamUribe not needed if you simply set `datatype:'json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem:
Its OK the way you doing.But I don't recommend it because it is not programmer friendly.
You can solve it many way.
Here is one solution that you want.
Process your controller before sending data at view this way after getting persons

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($persons);$i++)
{
   $persons[$i]->is_banned=$this->model_users->checkIfBanned($persons[$i]->name);
}
```

Now send this new $persons to your view.Your new view code will be like this

```
if($persons != "")
{
   foreach($persons as $p)
   {
       echo $p->name;
       echo $p->lastname;
       echo $p->is_banned;

  }
}
```

Hope you understand this.
For your second problem you can use  @charlietfl solution.
Here is summary:
Instead of calling multiple ajax call- call one ajax and return all the results as array.Like

```
function insertNewPost()
{
   //do your stuff;
   $data['content']="something";//it may be anything array,string
   //do your stuff;
   $data['count']="something";
   //do your stuff;
   $data['moreresult']="something";
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);
   exit();
}
```

Now at your js

```
function insertNewPost()
{
  var the_text = $('#post_text_input').val();
 if(the_text != "")
 {
   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:base_url+"controller/insertNewPost",
     data: {post_text: the_text},
     dataType: "JSON",
     success:function(response){
          //here you will get datas as response.content,response.count,response.moreresult
         //Now use them as you want as example
          $('#post_output').prepend(response.content);
          $('#post_text_input').val(response.count);
          $('#anotherid').val(response.moreresult);

     }
    });

 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I didn't know i had to call the `header()` and  in the ajax datatye "JSON" will try it and come back to you. I roger i have to read more about JSON. ;).